# Capture Image and display as Base64 String

Tags: java, android, image, base64

I'm an absolute newbie and want to build an app with Android that accesses the camera, takes a picture, cuts it and displays the result as Base64 code only. 
I already did some research and built the following code, but the Base64 output doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageUri = result.getUri();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //displaying bitmap works
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
    private String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        textView.setText(byteArray); //doesnt work
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added permission to use camera in manifest? Also is your app crushing?

Answer (score 1):

You have your textView.setText(byteArray); after your 'return' statement.  That statement will never be executed.  I think you should do this:

```
    String strReturn = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    textView.setText(strReturn);
    return strReturn;
```

Oh, yes, you are not calling the method to base64 encode the bitmap to string... you would do it this way:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = result.getUri();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                //HERE IS WHAT YOU NEED TO ADD
                textView.setText(bitmapToBase64(bitmap));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



}
private String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

    //THIS CHANGED A BIT
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip. I'm afraid it didn't help. I guess that bitmap is not passed from the first method (?) to the second. Could that be? And what is the best way to fix that?

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageUri = result.getUri();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }



    }
    private String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        textView.setText(encodedImage);
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Comment: Edited my original answer above.